# Can't install Pygame on Mac OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to install Pygame on Python 3.6, but when I write:

```
pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 36, in <module>
    from pip.utils.glibc import libc_ver
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/glibc.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    get_input()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 64, in get_input
    verb_word = command[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And I already did all the installs needed for pygame but I still get this... Anyone knows what is the problem and how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: The variable "command" might be overridden. Where does it come from?
(At the file /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py)

Comment: Pygame was finally added to the PyPA, did you try running `pip3 install pygame` instead? While I don't have MacOS, that might give you the correct installation of pygame. The reason I say this is because in the past I got this same error while trying to install it on Windows with a 64-bit version of Python (which wasn't supported by PyGame at the time, but now is)

Comment: @IdanMeyer if I remember correctly I may have downloaded it sometime ago just too see how it works. Do you think the problem is because of that?

Comment: @BradleyRobinson I tried, but I get same error..

Comment: @AndriusMalinauskas I really do not know, but it might be.

Comment: And by the way, I managed to install pygame on my Python 2.7 version (accidentally lol because I didn't added '3' to python when installing. But I can't manage to install it to 3.6 version.

Comment: @IdanMeyer I deleted that file and Pygame installed succesfully! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this (Specify a tag at the end):

```
$ pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame@1.9.3
```